# Como trazer fechado collapse do Swagger UI

Tags: swagger

Instalei Swagger para documentação de um software mas gostaria de alterar a visualização do meu template. Consegui fazer o fechamento do collapse quando carrega a página forçando um javascript ao iniciar, mas ficou com pequeno bug, pois tenho que clicar duas vezes para funcionar.

fiz algo asssim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.opblock-tag-section').find('div').slideUp();
  $('.opblock-tag-section').click(function(){
    $(this).find('div').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Fiz usando, "display", "none" na div também,e depois mando um "block" para voltar a mostrar. Mesmo assim ele dá uma travada e só funciona no segundo clique. Será que tem algo relacionado com o carregamento do json da minha api no swagger? Me questionei isso, porque ele monta a interface através da chamada do json, e estou alterando o comportamento do collapse depois de carregado.

Answer (score 0):

Nao sei voce ainda precisa, mas vou responder caso outra pessoa precise.

Em SwaggerConfig nessa parte aqui:

```
.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    { 
                       c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);
```

`DocExpansion.List` para collapse e
`DocExpansion.Full` para expanded